# sh conditionally pass an option to command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -f "/tmp/nodes" ]
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && VAL=$? ||

geth --datadir /root/.ethereum \
     ${VAL+"--nodekey \"/root/nodekey.txt\""} \     
     --networkid 1999 \
     --rpc \
     --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" \
```

I want the option `--nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt"` to be passed if the file `/tmp/nodes` exists. How can that be done more elegantly than an `if` with two nearly identical commands?

--EDIT--

This is the best I've been able to get working so far:

```
if [ $VAL -eq 0 ]; then
    /geth --datadir /root/.ethereum \
          --nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt" \
          # No dice
          # Would be nice if this worked so I didn't need the if
          # ${VAL+ --nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt" } \
          --networkid 1999 \
          --rpc \
          --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" 
else
    /geth --datadir /root/.ethereum \
          --networkid 1999 \
          --rpc \
          --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" \
fi
```

This is another line in the file and works fine:

```
ENODE_URL=$(/geth --datadir /root/.ethereum ${VAL+ --nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt"} --exec "${JS}" console 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/')
```

Comment: Yes, decide whether sh or bash. Bashism would only work, if you invoke it as `bash yourscript.sh`, not with `./yourscript.sh`".

Comment: `sh` I'm clearly not much of ba(sh) scripter so I have a bad habit of calling them the same thing.

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS and shell, whereas all other names are reserved for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph -- thus, staying away from all-caps names for your own variables avoids overriding system- or shell-defined variables by mistake.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could prove to us that `${VAL+ --nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt" }` *doesn't* work. Can you provide a [mcve] with code someone else can run to see it not working?

Comment: Note that your code `[ $VAL -eq 0 ]` is quite different from the `${VAL+ ...}` logic: The former checks numerical equality to 0, the latter checks whether the value is set (not even whether it's set to a non-empty string, but whether it's set *at all*; if you run `VAL=`, even that will make it set, and thus will cause `${var+foo}` to expand to `foo`)

Comment: ...if you want the empty string to be identical to the unset one, use `${var:+value}` instead of `${var+value}`. But anyhow -- again, if you're having trouble applying the advice in my answer, we need a [mcve] with code that can be copied-and-pasted (or run in an online interpreter like http://ideone.com/) to let people who aren't you (and don't have the prerequisites to run your script unmodified) see the problem themselves.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware the `-eq` and `${+}` tests are different. The problem doesn't seem to be that it's not expanding. It is expanding but not being interpreted as a valid option for some reason. I'll see if I can reduce the problem to something palatable. Currently, it's dependent on a bit of setup.

Comment: It looks like the problem is simply that `${VAL+"--nodekey \"/root/nodekey.txt\""}` is not the same as `${VAL+--nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt"}`.  Don't use quotes when you don't want them.

Comment: You do *not* "want the option `--nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt"` to be passed".  You want two arguments passed: `--nodekey` and `/root/nodekey.txt`.  By using quotes as you are, you are successfully passing the single argument `--nodekey "/root/nodekey.txt"` which is precisely *not* what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bashism here, but it's `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]`, as `[[` is a ksh extension adopted by bash. There's no point to using `$?` at all here, since you can just directly perform your assignment based on whether the `test -f` succeeds:

```
touch /tmp/nodes  # set us up for the truthy path
if test -f /tmp/nodes; then tmp_nodes_exists=1; else unset tmp_nodes_exists; fi
printf '%s\n' /tmp/nodes ${tmp_nodes_exists+"REALLY EXISTS" "(yes, really)"}
```

...properly emits as output (as run with `dash`, perhaps the most common minimal `/bin/sh` interpreter):

```
/tmp/nodes
REALLY EXISTS
(yes, really)
```

---

By contrast, to demonstrate that the other path fails as it should:

```
rm -f -- /tmp/nodes  # set us up for the falsey path
if test -f /tmp/nodes; then tmp_nodes_exists=1; else unset tmp_nodes_exists; fi
printf '%s\n' /tmp/nodes ${tmp_nodes_exists+"REALLY EXISTS" "(yes, really)"}
```

emits as output only:

```
/tmp/nodes
```